# Is the space of bounded monotonic continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ separable?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It is known that the Banach space $X = (C_b(\mathbb{R}), \Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty)$ is inseparable.

I am interested in constructing subsets of this metric space that are separable, and for my applications, monotonicity of the function is a possible assumption.

Is the space of bounded, continuous, monotonic functions on $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, endowed with the supremum norm, a separable metric space? If not, can you see further regularity conditions that ensure separability for functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

Metric space of continuous bounded monotonic functions on $\mathbb R$ is in fact metrically isomorphic to metric space of continuous monotonic functions on $[0, 1]$, isomorphism given by $X: C_{bm}(\mathbb R) \to C_{m}([0, 1])$, $(X(f))(x) = f(\tan(\pi (x - 1/2)))$, and $(X(f))(0) = \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$, $(X(f))(1) = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(1)$ - it's easy to check that $X(f)$ is continuous and $\|f_1 - f_2\| = \|X(f_1) - X(f_2)\|$.

As $C[0, 1]$ is separable, any subset of it is separable, and metric isomorphism preserves separability.

Comment: Thank you @mihaild. What if I remove monotonicity, and replace it with the property that the functions are in $C_b(\mathbb{R})$, and such that $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = C_{\pm}$, that is, the function has limit as $x \to \pm \infty$?

Comment: Yes, it will be the same. The important part is that we can specify function with arbitrary precision by defining it on finite segment + values at infinity.

Comment: This is fantastic @mihaild. Do you have a reference for this?